# How do I send a text message (SMS) with Twilio with React Native?

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-api

How do I send a text message with *Twilio* with native react?

I use this code but it not work:

```
fetch('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages',
{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },


            body: JSON.stringify({
                  user:'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  password:'f8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  to: '+3933850xxxx',
                  body: 'test',
                  from: '+3933850xxxx',

                   }),
                });
```

Are there any other ways?

Comment: did u read API document?

Comment: @Andrea can you share any example for the same ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sample code to send message using **twilio** API,

## Sample code

```
const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
 twilioClient.messages
   .create({ from: context.PHONE_NUMBER, to: phoneNumber, body: message })
   .then(x => {
     // If the SMS was successfully sent, remove the item from the list
     return twilioClient.sync
       .services(event.ServiceSid)
       .syncLists(event.ListUniqueName)
       .syncListItems(orderNumber)
       .remove();
   })
```

Comment: what is the context here?